# Customized new JUnit templates in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, templates, junit, customization

I've spent a few hours searching for this, and can't find it, so I'm asking. Why here?

How can I customize Eclipse so that when I create a new JUnit test class or method, it includes different items?  For other source, I'd just go into Window->Preferences, and change the templates.

But for JUnit, that doesn't seem to be possible.

I've recently installed MoreUnit, and that doesn't seem to help either.

Anyone have a pointer?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "it includes different items"?  Do you want particular methods to show up by default? Or do you want specify settings in the Run Configuration by default?  Or something else?

Comment: Specifically, I have some "test helper" methods I like to have available in my junit test classes.  I therefore would like to make my new test class extend a utility class.  Sadly, it appears that this is not possible.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It does not seem to be *directly* available.

The idea has been raised to save a file (like a JUnit empty file) as a template, to reuse it at future (JUnit for instance) creation time.
This is [bug 37440](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=37440)... and it is not very popular (since 2003!). And in `WON'T FIX` status...

The closest would be

`Window > Preferences > Java > Editor - Templates` and look under **"test method (JUnit4)"**

However, as mentioned in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg08613.html):

> but that will not affect the auto-generated JUnit test method stub templates.
>   In other words in the `New JUnit Test Case` dialog, one can select the methods of the class under test and test methods stubs are auto-generated.

To modify the template that creates these JUnit test method stubs... seems not possible at the moment.

[Bug 71783](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=71783) is somewhat related to this issue, regarding the comment templates of those methods.

Note: the generation of the JUnit class itself seems entirely hard-coded in the class

[**`org.eclipse.jdt.junit.wizards.NewTestCaseWizardPageOne`**](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/junit/wizards/NewTestCaseWizardPageOne.java.htm)

---

Speaking of template, you also needed to to provide VM arguments to all JUnit tests you run, manually copying them for every new configuration.
[Bug 37862](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=37862) has been set to address that and allow to create a Installed JRE for use with a JUnit testing, configuring it with the correct set of VM arguments.

Comment: Disappointing, no, I'd say insane. Eclipse was supposed to be an ecosystem with plugins and infinite customizability. This is ludicrous. (BTW, easily done in Xcode, from those bad, closed guys..)

Comment: This is incredibly disappointing. I trust nothing has changed in the last 6 years?

Comment: @kc2001 Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.